# jQuery onclick: position X / Y

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with position relative in this div are another divs that are absolute positioned. Now I want to receive the PositionX and PositionY Coordinates. It works very well when I click on a "free" spot in the div but when I click on a absolute positioned element inside this div I get wrong coordinates.

https://jsfiddle.net/vqb56uf3/2/

```js
$(".relative").click(function(e) {
  $(".clickIndicator").css({
    "left": e.offsetX + "px",
    "top": e.offsetY + "px",
    "display": "block"
  });
});
```

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: black;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: white;
}
.clickIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="relative">
  <div class="clickIndicator"></div>
  <div class="absolute" style="top: 30px; left: 90px;"></div>
  <div class="absolute" style="top: 200px; left: 340px;"></div>
  <div class="absolute" style="top: 140px; left: 79px;"></div>
  <div class="absolute" style="top: 230px; left: 211px;"></div>
  <div class="absolute" style="top: 90px; left: 450px;"></div>
  <div class="absolute" style="top: 80px; left: 260px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The coordinates are not wrong, you're rather retrieving wrong values. `offsetX/Y` gives you the coordinates relative to the event target. The you're using the same coordinates assuming they are relative to `.relative`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the coords relatively the window use [`pageX`](https://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/) and [`pageY`](https://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/).

> The mouse position relative to the left edge of the document

Also, you can calculate relatively the element by increase the `.relative` position, like this:

```js
$(".relative").click(function(e) {
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  $(".clickIndicator").css({
    "left": e.pageX - offset.left + "px",
    "top": e.pageY - offset.top + "px",
    "display": "block"
  });
});
```

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: black;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: white;
}
.clickIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="relative">
  <div class="clickIndicator"></div>
  <div class="absolute" style="top: 30px; left: 90px;"></div>
  <div class="absolute" style="top: 200px; left: 340px;"></div>
  <div class="absolute" style="top: 140px; left: 79px;"></div>
  <div class="absolute" style="top: 230px; left: 211px;"></div>
  <div class="absolute" style="top: 90px; left: 450px;"></div>
  <div class="absolute" style="top: 80px; left: 260px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The offset is relative to the event target. To get the X,Y co-ordinates of the click event you need to take the location of the target into account. The old school JavaScript way to do this is as follows:

```
var element = e.target,
    bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),
    elemRect = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
    offsetX  = elemRect.left - bodyRect.left + e.offsetX,
    offsetY  = elemRect.top - bodyRect.top + e.offsetY;
```